# Column 'nid' in field list is ambiguous query in Drupal6

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm trying to create a block for display content but I'm getting this error:

```
user warning: Column 'nid' in field list is ambiguous query: SELECT nid, title FROM node nd LEFT JOIN content_type_efemerides cte ON ( nd.nid = cte.nid ) WHERE type = '0' AND field_efemerides_fecha_value = '1' in D:\Webserver\htdocs\intranet\sites\all\modules\efemerides_form\efemerides_form.module on line 12.
```

Line 12 have this code:

```
8 $today = getdate();
9 $type = "efemerides";
10
11 $query = "SELECT nid, title FROM  {node} nd LEFT JOIN {content_type_efemerides} cte ON ( nd.nid = cte.nid ) WHERE type = '%d' AND field_efemerides_fecha_value = '%d'";
12 $query_result = db_query($query, $type, $today);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nid` in your select statement is ambiguous (as the error message states), you just need to qualify it with a table alias:

```
$query = "SELECT nd.nid, nd.title FROM  {node} nd LEFT JOIN {content_type_efemerides} cte ON ( nd.nid = cte.nid ) WHERE type = '%s' AND field_efemerides_fecha_value = '%s'";
```

Also string replacements should be done using `%s` instead of `%d` (`%d` being for decimals)

Comment: Thanks I made the changes as you suggested but still not working, the error dissapear but data is not displayed. This is the function: [link](http://pastebin.com/JigwJEeX) what's wrong? Why I can't get data from DB? Also thanks for your reply